# IIS Worker Process is full but CPU memory is low

Tags: asp.net, iis, webforms, crystal-reports

We have a production server with a good hardware requirements. We have an app and a database server separately. And now, we are currently, experiencing a heavy load in Worker Process that causes the users to feel the system is too slow. But the memory and CPU utilization of both server are less than 10%. When this happens, the user cant generate report from crystal report. What we do is we generate the report first at crystal report and downloaded it as pdf. We currently dont use crystal report viewer. And this problem will only be solve if we recycle the application pool which is too hard for us because the user will be logged out in the system. Please help me.

So we tried to put all disposing code in crystal report regeneration, we tried to increase ram size to 256GB, refactor some of the stored procedures that are quite slow

Comment: Did you bump up the AppPool settings as well to match?

Comment: Low CPU and memory with long request wait time is usually a sign of threadpool starvation. Are you doing your database calls using `async/await` pattern?

Comment: @JohanP we are using rad telerik for most of the control. this has an async/await

Comment: @lloyd what do you mean? could you please elaborate it further?

Comment: Are you doing any `.Result` calls on the async code?

Comment: [iis-cpu-settings](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/iis/configuration/system.applicationhost/applicationpools/add/cpu)

Comment: @lloyd thank you for this link. i tried setting the  Maximum Worker Processes to 0 and the system becomes fast enough to handle our users. however, the users' sessions were dumped. how could we solve this one?

Comment: @JohanP i appreciate your comment sir. but right now we need an immediate solution and we dont have quite time to modify codes

Comment: If you're doing sync over async, you will bring all your servers to a grind at some point if load increases, your only quick fix is to scale up.